# Prevent control animation when setting RadioButton.Checked

Tags: delphi

I set two radiobuttons' Checked property on a second form before showing that form. Each time the button is clicked to set the Checked properties and show the form I invert ("NOT") the Checked for each radiobutton. Then upon showing the form one clearly can see the animation (Checked properties being changed) of the radiobuttons happening. It does not happen on first run but happens on each subsequent show of the form.

I would like to prevent the animation and just have the radiobuttons show the newly set checked state when the form is shown. Is there a way to do it?

Having the radiobuttons on a disabled panel or making them invisible before setting the Checked does not work.

[image]

Form1:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.RadioButton1.Checked := not Form2.RadioButton1.Checked;
  Form2.RadioButton2.Checked := not Form2.RadioButton1.Checked;

  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Form1 DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 81
  ClientWidth = 249
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 36
    Top = 24
    Width = 157
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Set Radios and Show Form2'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Form2:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    RadioButton1: TRadioButton;
    RadioButton2: TRadioButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Hide;
end;

end.
```

Form2 DFM:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 131
  ClientWidth = 176
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 44
    Top = 90
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Hide'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object RadioButton1: TRadioButton
    Left = 38
    Top = 20
    Width = 113
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'RadioButton1'
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object RadioButton2: TRadioButton
    Left = 38
    Top = 44
    Width = 113
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'RadioButton2'
    TabOrder = 2
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you checking and unchecking your Radio Buttons in such way? You do know that the purpose of Radio Buttons is the ability to simply check one and the rest of them will be automatically unchecked. But since your code already does this manually perhaps you might want to replace these Radio Buttons of yours with Check Boxes. You already have code that will switch their checked state between them. Check Boxes unlike Radio Buttons don't have any animation.

Comment: The code is an experiment and in no way part of a project nor is it something that I would use in a project. It was setup to see how the animation behaves and that is how I stumbled upon it. I wanted to know if there is some sort of workaround to "the issue"

Comment: I figured as such hence why I only posted a comment. Any way I don't think it is possible to completely disable Radio Button animation as it seems to just be a wrapper for common win control. Therefore controlling whether it is animated or not is done by Windows itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DoubleBuffered` property of the `TRadioButton`s to `True`.

Comment: Setting DoubleBuffered to true does indeed prevent the animation. Unfortunately that always prevents the animation. So to fix I just set it to true whenever I show the form and set it to false again whenever I click on one of the radiobuttons. Your suggestion allows me to do it so accepted answer it is. Thanks

Comment: Fairly gross overkill!

Comment: Setting DoubleBuffered to true does not prevent the animation it only makes it happen more quickly so it is less noticeable.

Comment: @ SilverWarrior. I am happy with that as it is just the noticeable part that I was wondering about.

Comment: @David. Please elaborate

Comment: DoubleBuffering does way more than suppress animation.

Comment: @David. Agreed. It is a weak workaround for an unnecessary requirement.